# Speed up update query under executemany cx_orcale

Tags: python, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I have around 0.5 million rows which needs to be updated in two table of oracle sql server .
I divided 0.5 into 100K rows and tried executemany but it is taking on forever. I have 10 files with 0.5 million in each file. this would take me forever to update in the table. Need suggestion to improve or speed up the process.

My code:

```
    insert_batch_size=1000
    def UpdateDBWith_Y(Processed_HSMemberFileDf,connection,cursor):
    try:
        Columns = {'ccd_aadhaar_seeding_status':'Y','CCD_LST_MOD_BY':'SYSTEM'}
        Processed_HSMemberFileDf=Processed_HSMemberFileDf.assign(**Columns)
        Processed_HSMemberFileDf.drop('ADHAAR_SEEDING_STATUS', axis=1, inplace=True)
        ListAcctoDB=['ccd_aadhaar_seeding_status','CCD_LST_MOD_BY','PAN']
        Processed_HSMemberFileDf = Processed_HSMemberFileDf[ListAcctoDB]
        bind_update=Processed_HSMemberFileDf.values.tolist()
        print(len(bind_update))
        length=0
        bind_update_chunks = [bind_update[x:x+insert_batch_size] for x in range(0, len(bind_update), insert_batch_size)]
        for insert_chunk in bind_update_chunks:
            start_time = time.time()                  
            _updatequery="update UCIDBA.client_code_dtls set ccd_aadhaar_seeding_status = :1,CCD_LST_MOD_BY=:2,CCD_LST_MOD_DT=SYSDATE where CCD_PAN_NO= :3"
            _updatequery_chld="update UCIDBA.client_code_child_dtls set ccc_aadhaar_seeding_status = :1,CCC_LST_MOD_BY=:2,CCC_LST_MOD_DT=SYSDATE where CCC_PAN_NO= :3"
            logging.info("UpdateDBWith_Y:->Update Query : |" +_updatequery)
            logging.info("UpdateDBWith_Y:->Update Query child: |" +_updatequery_chld)
            cursor.executemany(_updatequery,insert_chunk)
            connection.commit()
            cursor.executemany(_updatequery_chld,insert_chunk)
            connection.commit()
            length=length+len(insert_chunk)
            logging.info("UpdateDBWith_Y:->inserted till : |" +str(length))
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        return True
    except Exception  as e :
        logging.exception("UpdateDBWith_Y:->: |")  
        return False
```

Is there any other way to speedup or use executemany ?

Comment: Assuming your chunks are being constructed correctly, my immediate question would be... is CCD_PAN_NO indexed in both tables? If not, there's likely to be a lot of full table scanning going on which, with a very large table, is going to be slow

Comment: There is no "oracle sql server". Oracle and SQL Server are completely different products. Please edit your question to be less confusing.

Comment: Notwithstanding the misspelling in the title, I think it's clear that this refers to Oracle database (via the cx_Oracle Python module)